# How to store query results as member variables from within a class using a mysqli function?

Tags: php, mysqli

At the moment I use mysqli_fetch_object('ModelClass') to instantiate my class with all the query results... but... I'd like to keep all my "business" logic inside the model_class.

I tried...

```
class ModelClass
{
    function __construct($model_id)
    {
         if($model_id)
         {
             //query code goes here...

             return $mysqli_result->mysqli_fetch_object('ModelClass',$model_id);
         }
    }
}

$model = new ModelClass();
```

That method seems a bit wonky. Essentially I'm instantiating the class twice there.

I could also return the results as an array then cycle through storing each member variable...

Is there a different / better way to go about storing query results within a class into member variables?

[php mysqli_fetch_object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php)

Answer (score 0):

You could store the result as a different class in a single member variable:

```
class ModelClass {
    public $result;
    function __construct($model_id)
    {
         if($model_id)
         {
             //query code goes here...

             $result = $mysqli_result->mysqli_fetch_object('ModelClassResult',$model_id);
         }
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
$model = new ModelClass();
// Now access $model->result-><fieldname>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I don't follow why you would want to include your instantiation logic within the object you are trying to instantiate.  In essence, what you are trying to implement is a factory pattern.  I would think you would be better off building a class to serve as the factory to instantiate such objects.  The instantiation logic (i.e. MySQL interactions) could take place in that factory.  Usage might look something like this:

```
$model_object = mysql_factory::instantiate('ModelClass', $model_id);
```

You could then use this factory to instantiate any sort of class (even classes other than ModelClass) if you like using the same exact methods.  There is no reason to put SQL interaction into every class you might want to instantiate in this manner.

Comment: I haven't used the Factory pattern before but it seems like it's a bit overkill for what I'm trying to accomplish. Why wouldn't Barmer's answer be a better solution?

Comment: Also, I can't seem to find any factory pattern solutions for mysql... I can find examples for "objects" like VehicleFactory etc., those make sense to me. I'm having a hard time conceptualizing a "mysql_factory", can you show me a example or explain it better for me. Thanks

Comment: @payling  Say you want to now have another class other than `ModelClass` that you want to instantiate in the same way.  Are you going to add duplicate code in that class to have all your MySQL connection and object fetching logic, or are you going to refactor that out to have all your MySQL logic for fetching the object in a common class that handles this.

Comment: @payling  I would think the second solution is best as if you ever need to make changes in how the object is retrieved from the database (say you want to change database implementations later on, or want to add the ability to implement a cache in front of the database), it would be preferable to have one place where you need to change this code, not duplicate code across a number of classes.  One of the key tenets in OO design is that you want your classes to basically do one specialized thing, not spread common logic across a number of classes.

Comment: @payling As far as factory pattern for MySQL, the MySQL part is not the logical leap you need to make, it is the understanding of the factory pattern.  Once you understand that the pattern serves to give you a single class to build other class objects, making that pattern work with MySQL is just an implementation detail. The implementation wouldn't necessarily need to be much more than what you currently have in your constructor. You pass in the name of the class the object is going to be instantiated to and the specific id value to use and return the object.